# Router on NodeJS express

Tags: node.js, express, router

I'm creating a nodeJS application and i was starting my app with  `nodemon app.js`, everything was working well but when i stopped to restart it was impossible to restart. I found nothing about that on internet.

For informations i followed the node postgres documentation for the project structure using async/await : https://node-postgres.com/guides/async-express

I'm stucked in that problem and can't understand why it happens, I just want to restart my projet

Thanks for your help and have a nice day !

[error at launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKOEM.png)

Comment: Please create a minimal code that reproduces the error and place it on your question. Also, please post your error (that makes that monimal code) as text.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the following requirement: `const Router = require('express-promise-router');` to: `const Router = require('router');`